# Fatal error: Class 'PPXmlMessage' not found . what is it?

Tags: php, paypal, masspay

I was looking the masspay php sdk provided by paypal.com(merchant-sdk-php-master from github) in my sandbox.But it gaves me an error when i tried to pay to one of my sandbox test account. here is the response from paypal server. can anyone help me to fix this issue

```
$massPayRequest = new MassPayRequestType(); on line 11
```

Errors

```
Fatal error: Class 'MassPayRequestType' not found 0n c:..\x\y\z\MassPay.php on line 11
```

I didn't get what is the exact problem . I thought it was some problem in php lib sdk files.

So please help me.............

Comment: Have you included the class? Have you checked that the file path is correct or the class is located within include path?

Comment: no ,that class not included so If I included the class file then again showing Fatal error: Class 'PPXmlMessage' not found . How can solve this issue

Comment: the pack I using is here https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php . Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the merchant-sdk for PayPal but you are not including the core classes provided in the sdk-core. Anyone getting this simply go to https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php and add the core classes.